# Weird behavior of tcl comment inside if/else block. Is it a bug of tcl interpreter?

Tags: tcl, comments

I caught very strange bug(?) which took me almost whole day to find it in real application. In the code there was a `elseif` block which was commented out and it led to execution of code which (as I thought) could not ever be executed.

I simplified the testcase which reproduces this odd tcl behavior.

```
proc funnyProc {value} {
  if {$value} {
    return "TRUE"
#  } elseif {[puts "COMMENT :)"] == ""} {
#    return "COMMENT"
  } else {
    return "FALSE"
  }
  return "IT'S IMPOSSIBLE!!!"
}

puts [funnyProc false]
```

What do you think this program will output?

1. The `puts` in the comment line is executed. It's impossible from any programming language POV.
2. The line after the block `if {...} {return} else {return}` is executed as well. It's impossible from `true/false` logic.

I know that tcl-comment behaves like a command with the name `#` and consumes all arguments until EOL. And tcl parser do not like unbalanced curly brackets in comments. But this case is out of my understanding.

Maybe I missed something important? How to correctly comment out such `elseif` blocks, so do not have these weird side-effects?

Comment: That is crazy! I note that if you add "{" right after the hash and "}" at the end of the `elseif` line, the code behaves as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `#` is only a comment when Tcl is looking for the start of a command, and the first time it sees it above (when parsing the `if`), it's looking for a `}` in order to close the earlier `{`. This is a consequence of the Tcl parsing rules; `if` is just a command, not a special construct.

The effect that Ernest noted is because it increases the nesting level of the braces on that line, which makes it part of the argument that runs from the end of the `if {$value} {` line to the start of the `} else {` line. Then the `#` becomes special when `if` evaluates the script. (Well, except it's all bytecode compiled, but that's an implementation detail: the observed semantics are the same except for some really nasty edge cases.)

Comment: It seems you are right. If I press Return just after the first `#` to split the first comment line, the behavior is not changed. But now it's clearly understandable that there are two pieces of code: the empty comment line and non-commented `elseif` with just a comment in its body. Thanks. PS. Syntax highlighting in editors I'm using can't handle this case properly, that is misleading.

Comment: @GrAnd: Re highlighting: Yes, it's known. Consequence of (all? most?) highlighters expecting an lexer/parser model, which doesn't fit Tcl too well.